# MFC: CListCtrl.EnableWindow(FALSE), but still scrollable?

Tags: mfc

I have a CListCtrl list box which I would like to toggle betwen full functionality, and being read-only (ie the user can not change the selection).

The member function `CListCtrl.EnableWindow(FALSE)` seems designed for this, except that when I call

```
m_listCtrl.EnableWindow(FALSE);
GetDlgItem( IDC_LIST_CTRL_EDIT )->EnableWindow(FALSE);
```

the scrollbars on it stop working (assuming I have more content than will fit in the CListCtrl).

Is there an elegant way to achieve the read-only-but-still-scrolls behaviour, other than overriding mouse handlers, or resetting the selection on each page refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by deriving your own class from CListCtrl and handling the [LVN_ITEMCHANGING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification.  See my sample code below...

```
void MyClistCtrl::OnLvnItemchanging(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
    {
    *pResult = FALSE;

    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    // If there is no selection allowed, prevent the item from changing 
    if ((pNMLV->uNewState & LVIS_SELECTED) /* check flag to if it should be read only ie check radiobutton state*/)
        {
        *pResult = TRUE;
        }

    }
```

The code above will unconditionally prevent a selection while still allowing the scroll bar to function.  The ability to control this behavior can be added to the "if" statement (eg. checking a flag tied to a radio button).